# Problems about Install apk from invite email of crashlytics

Tags: android

I use Crashlytics to publish test version apk , when my members got the invite email, they open it and click "Check It Out" on Android device, but stock by this warning > "Safari is required"

[image]

So, does the link of Crashlytics only work on Safari? How Android device install Crashlytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex from Fabric here. For iOS apps, the email invitation needs to be opened in Safari on their iPhone or iPad. For Android apps, this restriction doesn't exist. From your screenshot, it seems like the user is opening an invitation to test an iOS app on their Android device, which won't work. But you did mention you're testing an APK, so I'd definitely like to look into this more. If you let me know the package name and your Fabric org, I can dig into it on our backend.